# adding an image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a chess game and is really just starting to learn jquery. I have a 8*8 board made and I'm trying to add a rook to its starting position in the bottom right, how can I do this?
I tried making a css for the image and add as id.

HTML
    
    
    
    
    chess

```
<h1> Game Board </h1>
<table id="gameBoard">
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
<img id="whiterook">
</img>
<footer>
This is an example of creating a chess Game.
</footer>
<script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/chess.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(function() {

 var row = new Array(9).join('<td></td>');
 var body = new Array(9).join('<tr>' + row + '</tr>');

 });
```

CSS

```
#gameBoard {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: solid 1px black;
}
#gameBoard td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#gameBoard tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: black;
}
#gameBoard tbody tr:nth-child(2n+2) td:nth-child(2n +1) {
  background-color: black;
}
#whiterook{
background-image: url(../images/Chess_tile_rl.png);
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
top:300px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing it with CSS instead of `<img src="URL">`?

Comment: The Javscript never adds `body` to the table.

Comment: @Barmar if I do img src in javascript how would I put it in?

Comment: Could just be a typo, but `img` elements are self-closing void tags, so no need for `<img></img>`. Have you tried declaring unique identifiers for each table cell? This could make it easier to target specific elements in order to append or insert images where needed. With the various jQuery methods on hand, you're spoiled for choice when it comes to manipulating the DOM to insert or add elements, so you may need to do a bit of exploring to find the right one that'll suit the task at hand and accomplish it in the most efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of questionable things going on with this setup/solution but I will answer the question you did have.

```
$('#whiterook').attr('src','/images/Chess_tile_rl.png');
```

If you are adding the src to the img tag then you can remove the background-image styling of the #whiterook element. The img element is what is called a replaced inline element which does not support the background-image property.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a game with CSS would be kind of difficult, i strongly recommend you to use html5 and javascript, here are some easy step by step tutorials for a chess game :

http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/11008-learning-to-write-a-javascript-chess-game/

https://geeksretreat.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/html-5-canvas-chess-board/

Hope it helps !